# Fetching Data From Mysql With PHP, Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have database with fields branch, name, code_member, status etc.

I am trying to fetch Names in dropdown menu with branch by group mysql query. And Then Show Details Of NAME Selected In Dropdown List. But No Results are shown.

Selection Of Branch, Name And Auto Entering of Name In Search Box is working perfectly. But After That ID, Name, Branch,Code Number etc. data is not getting displayed.

There are three pages used. index.php, findName.php and searchfinal.php

Code I tried Is As Follows :

**index.php :**

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
       {
          $(".branch").change(function()
       {
            var branch=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'branch='+ branch;

     $.ajax
           ({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "findName.php",
                 data: dataString,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(html)
              {
              $(".getname").html(html);
              } 
            });
         });
        });
   </script>

   <script>
         $(document).ready(function()
             {
                  $('#getname').change(function() {
                  $('#name').val($(this).val());
                });
             });
   </script>

</head>

<body>

  Branch :
     <select name="branch" class="branch">
        <option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
     <?php
       $sql=mysql_query("select branch from mutualbs group by branch");
           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
       {

              $branch=$row['branch'];
                 echo '<option value="'.$branch.'">'.$branch.'</option>';
       } ?>
     </select> <br/><br/>

   Name :
     <select name="getname" id="getname" class="getname">
             <option selected="selected">--Select Name--</option>
     </select>

   <br><br>

   <hr>

   <form method="get">   
         <label for="name">Name To Search :</label>
         <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

         <button class="btnSearch">Search</button>   
   </form>
   <br><br>

   <table id="resultTable" style="color:#ff0000;">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>MBS Number</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th>Status</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
            <tbody></tbody> //** Results Are Not Getting Shown
   </table>

    <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.btnSearch').click(function(){
                makeAjaxRequest();
            });

            $('form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                makeAjaxRequest();
                return false;
            });

      function makeAjaxRequest() {
             $.ajax({
                    url: 'searchfinal.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    data: {name: $('input#name').val()},
                    success: function(response) {
                       $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
                    }
                 });
              }
            });
      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Till Search Button Everything working OK... But After Clicking Search Button, No Results i.e. ID, Name, Code Number, Branch And Status Shown..

Other Codes :

**searchfinal.php**

```
<?
require_once 'Connection.simple.php';
$conn = dbConnect();
    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $data = "%".$_GET['name']."%";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mutualbs WHERE name like ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $results = $stmt->execute(array($data));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
   }
   if(empty($rows)) {
    echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td colspan='4'>There were not records</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
   }
   else {
       foreach ($rows as $row) {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row['code_number']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row['branch']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Need Help....

Comment: Please format code with proper indents for readability

Comment: do you see any errors on the console !

Comment: Can't insert jQuery code in page before jQuery itself gets loaded. The code in head will throw error in console `$ is not defined`. Use browser console (F12) to check for errors

Comment: what about this `$jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` after the `bootstrap.min.js` call.

Comment: not sure why you are using `$jQuery`. That's fine if it is defined by you in the jQuery file, but the norm is to use either `$` or `jQuery`. My guess is this is also an error

Comment: @charlietfl ohh...it's my minor...or say major mistake...i removed $ from $jQuery and code worked....thanx for help...please put it as your answer so I can mark it as Right Answer...

Comment: @DrManishJoshi in browser console should see that as error and line that it is thrown on and therefore give you something to look for when code isn't working